Is it possible to override the Localizer("string") method in ASP.NET MVC?
The Localizer method is used in conjunction with .resx files in the appropriate path. This all works out of the box with barely any config, just .AddViewLocalization() in my Program.cs.
However I'd like to modify it so that the localised strings are transformed, for example I'd like to apply .ToUpper() on them and some other tweaks.
How can I override the default behaviour? I understand I possibly need to create some kind of custom Localizer, but I've not been able to figure out how, or how to implement it and have it work with minimal configuration with the existing setup.
